# Why do processes I fork get systemd as their parent?

Tags: c, linux, fork, systemd

I am learning fork() in Linux, and here is my program:

```
  1 #include <stdio.h>
  2 #include <stdlib.h>
  3 #include <unistd.h>
  4 int main(void){
  5         int pid;
  6         pid = fork();
  7         if(pid < 0){
  8                 exit(1);
  9         }
 10         if(pid == 0){
 11                 fork();
 12                 fork();
 13                 printf("pid:%d ppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
 14                 exit(0);
 15                 }
 16         else{
 17                 printf("parent pid:%d ppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
 18                 exit(0);
 19         }       
 20        
 21 }
```

Sometimes it worked fine, with result like this:

```
./test1.out
parent pid:27596 ppid:21425
pid:27599 ppid:27597
pid:27597 ppid:27596
pid:27598 ppid:27597
pid:27600 ppid:27598
```

But the result was not consistent, more often than not it worked like this:

```
parent pid:27566 ppid:21425
pid:27567 ppid:27566
pid:27568 ppid:27567
pid:27569 ppid:1599
pid:27570 ppid:1599
```

Which makes no sense to me, so I typed ***$ps aux*** to find out what process 1599 is:(with some columns deleted)

```
  USER       PID  VSZ   RSS    STAT START   COMMAND
  linux     1599  63236  6316   Ss   09:03  /lib/systemd/systemd --user
```

Can anybody help me straighted things up?

Comment: Try to have the parent `wait()` for the children before exiting.

Answer (score 7):

The "inconsistency" you observed is because sometimes, the parent process(es) exited *before* their child process(es) terminated. So, these child processes become ["orphans"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orphan_process) as their
parent processes are not [*waiting*](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html) for them.  As a result, they are "re-parented" to the init process. 
While traditionally the process id of the "init" process is 1, it's not always true. [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_Exit.html) leaves it as *implementation-defined*:

> The parent process ID of all of the existing child processes and
>   zombie processes of the calling process shall be set to the process ID
>   of an implementation-defined system process. That is, these processes
>   shall be inherited by a special system process.

Thus you see a particular PID as the parent (1599 in your example), which happens to be "init" process equivalent on your Linux.
The [systemd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) is an init variant used in Debian Linux distributions - which follows a slightly more complicated implementation.

In essense, what you observed is pretty normal. Ideally, you should *reap* all the processes in order to avoid [zombie processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zombie_process).

Comment: Thank you! It really helps me a lot:)

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that, sometimes, a race condition happens, and the parent dies before the child. Hence, the child becomes children from init process. In your case, that must be systemd.

Anyway, be advised that running `fork(); fork();` will produce 4 processes, which is (probably) not what you intend. Use control structure as you did with the first one to have fine control on the behaviour of your program.

Comment: Try pstree to observe the process hierarchy.

Answer (score 2):

It is because the parent process terminates first.
In Linux there are no ophan processes. They are assigned to the `init` process.

If you want to control your processes so that child process terminates first, make parent process wait. Using `wait()` sys_call.

```
Example:

   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <unistd.h>
   int main(void)
   {
        int pid;
        int pid2;
        pid = fork();
        if(pid < 0){
                 exit(1);
        }
        if(pid == 0){ // child process
            pid2 = fork()
            if (pid2 < 0)
                exit(1);
            if (pid2 == 0)
            {
                printf("pid:%dppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
                exit(0);
            }
            wait();
            printf("pid:%d ppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            exit(0);
        }
        else{         // parent process
           wait();
           printf("parent pid:%d ppid:%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
           exit(0);
        }       
        return 0;            
  }
```

> systemd is an init system used in Linux distributions to bootstrap the
>   user space and manage all processes subsequently

Comment: Terminology: it is conventional to call a process an "orphan" when it continues to run after its *original* parent terminates, notwithstanding the fact that such processes are re-parented to the init process.  In that sense, there are certainly orphan processes in Linux; they are fairly commonplace.